# How to tell a class is deprecated in Java1.5

Tags: java

I created a new class in my Application like `A1.java` and now I have to tell all developer `A.java` is deprecated so everyone should use `A1.java` because `A.java` is deprecated now.

Comment: You can mention that in the javadoc.

Comment: Not a duplicate; this question is _how_ to deprecate a class, while that question is how to _handle_ it (should one deprecated methods that use that class and so on).

Comment: @StephenC Its not Duplicate question

Comment: @subodh - You are entitled to your opinion ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Deprecated` tag should work ideally.

You can say replaced by `@link A1`

How to use `@link` - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#link

**Sample Code**

```
/**
@deprecated 
This class has been replaced by {@link A1}
**/
@Deprecated
public class A
```

Comment: @subodh updated post with a link

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * @deprecated
 * @author GS
 *
 */
public class A {
```

This will do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Use `@Deprecated` annotation

```
@Deprecated
public class MyClass{
 ....
}
```